# string::find returning a value of -1 when it's expected to return a value of 0 [C++]

Tags: c++

I have the following code that doesn't work:

```
string line;
string line_sub;
size_t open_tag_start;
const string open_tag = "<image>";
const int open_len = open_tag.length() + 1;

open_tag_start = line.find(open_tag);
line_sub = line.substr(open_tag_start, open_len);
```

When I try to run this code, I get the following error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
what():  basic_string::substr
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I've figured out that this error is occurring because the `line.find` line is returning a value of `-1` to the variable `open_tag_start`. I can rectify the problem by hard coding a value of `0` into the variable `open_tag_start`, but I need this to a generic algorithm that will be able to find the tag at any point in the line, so it has to be a variable. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

Here's some more info.

My goal with this code if to extract a `string line_sub` from `string line`, which does indeed contain a string, and when I set `size_t open_tag_start = 0`, I am able to compile and execute the code and observe the expected output. `line` is not empty and my problem is that when I replace

```
line_sub = line.substr(open_tag_start, open_len);
```

with

```
line_sub = line.substr(0, open_len);
```

my problem goes away and I can compile and execute the code.

This is a short version of my program that contains only the parts that are causing the problems. Attempting to compile this code will yield the error message detailed above. The file `rss.xml` is the RSS feed for engadget.com http://www.engadget.com/rss.xml

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

void get_tag_contents(ifstream& rssfile, string line, string open_tag);

int main()
{
    const string open_tag = "<image>";

    ifstream rssfile;
    rssfile.open("rss.xml");
    string line;

    getline(rssfile, line, '\n');
    get_tag_contents(rssfile, line, open_tag);

    return 0;
}

void get_tag_contents(ifstream& rssfile, string line, string open_tag)
{   
    const int open_len = open_tag.length() + 1;
    size_t open_tag_start;
    string line_sub;

    open_tag_start = line.find(open_tag);
    line_sub = line.substr(open_tag_start, open_len);
}
```

Comment: Please post a short, self-contained program that compiles and demonstrates the problem. There's an important detail we're missing in whatever code you've omitted.

Comment: I've updated my question with the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you've left out some code, `line` is an empty string, so of course `find` fails. It is your expectation that is in error, not the `find` function—that's all!

As a side note, you don't need to compensate for `'\0'` when using C++ strings. Get rid of the `+ 1`.

Comment: ...and since size_t is unsigned, it's not returning `-1`, it's returning `string::npos`.

Comment: @bgporter -- Nonetheless, string::npos is defined, in the standard, to have a value of -1.

Comment: @PigBen: Technically, it isn't - and can't be - defined to have the value of -1 as this outside the range of values representable as a `size_type`. It's defined to be a `size_type` with an initializer of `-1` so it has the value of `-1` _after_ conversion to a `size_type` which is a large positive number.

Comment: I've worded my question wrong and I've provided an update to make things a bit more clear.

Answer (score 2):

If the substring isn't found in the string, then the `find()` method will return `std::string::npos`, which is a size_type of value -1.  When you call `substr()` with `open_tag_start` equalling -1, then this is what throws the out_of_range error.

Comment: Tehcnically, a `std::string::size_type` can't take the value `-1` because it's an unsigned type. `std::string::npos` is the largest number representable as a `size_type` which is the same as `-1` cast to a `size_type` but isn't `-1`.

Comment: I've worded my question wrong and I've provided an update to make things a bit more clear.

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, you **must** check the return value of find() in case the search fails.

```
std::string line("this is <image> a test");
std::string line_sub;
const std::string open_tag = "<image>";

size_t open_tag_start = line.find(open_tag);

if (open_tag_start != std::string::npos)
{
    line_sub = line.substr(open_tag_start, open_tag.length());
}

std::cout << line << "\n" << line_sub << "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, are you sure that `line` contains `<image>` ?? One thing to consider is that `<ImaGe>` may be capitalized in some way. Also, i dont quite see what you're trying to do, because `line_sub` (given that your code works) will just return `enter code here` and the next character after that.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Remember to sanitize your return values. If find returns -1, deal with the problem or throw an error.